# When would the ItemContainerGenerator.Status enumeration return GeneratorStatus.Error?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, itemcontainergenerator

When would the `ItemContainerGenerator.Status` enumeration return `GeneratorStatus.Error` in WPF? Has anyone encountered such a situation? Just wondering, as I mainly work in Silverlight and the `GeneratorStatus` doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `ItemContainerGenerator` (if used for example in a ListBox) will create a `ListBoxItem` for each data item the `ListBox` is bound to.

The standard `ItemContainerGenerator` in `PresentationFramework` has an private class called '`Generator`'. When this class is instantiated by the `ItemContainerGenerator` it sets the `ItemContainerGenerator` class's Status as `GeneratorStatus.GeneratingContainers`, then when the `ItemContainerGenerator` calls `Dispose` on the `Generator` instance, the `Generator` class sets the `ItemContainerGenerator` status to `GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated`.

`GeneratorStatus.Error` is never used in the standard implmentation, but if your rolling your own `ItemsControl`, you can roll your own `ItemContainerGenerator` and maybe use the error status in your code.

Comment: Yes you're right, I edited the question to be more concise. Do you have an answer also? :->

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Is there any info out there about when it is a recommended situation to set `GeneratorStatus.Error` if one implements their own `ItemContainerGenerator`?

Comment: well, if your custom ItemsContainerGenerator is creating elaborate containers that may not be supported properly by the bound data type you could set this status to error, and then use it in you WPF code to check on the status of your custom ItemsControl's bindings etc